# Any Idea how to load a nib from other Project under same Workspace - IOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, nib

I have a problem in loading a nib which is present in another project under same workspace, when I try to load it is crashing by saying CRASH: 'Could not load NIB in bundle:.. like that.. Any Idea how to load a view in this case???

Hope codes are not necessary for this question.

thanks...

Comment: you need to drag that nib file in your project also..

Comment: I did tested like that, It is asking corresponding .h and outlet connections are not linked properly because .m is in another project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add all xib files in main project, because xib is a resource it will not be a part of .a file.